# Filtering/Validating the CSV file in R

Tags: r, csv

I am having trouble in filtering the CSV file.

My Dataset and its datastructure somewhat looks like this:

```
ID    Date        Time       Product_no  Product_IM_no  Pro_Name
(num) (Date)     (time)        (num)       (num)         (Char)
1    2-Oct-01  00:40 to 1:30   2152.5     71213.4        Aspire
1    2-Oct-01    02:10         21547.9    7122.3         Pla and Aspire ##Remove the row because Pro_name can have either Pluto or Aspire or Pla.
1    2.10.01     02:50         21537.9    7157.8         pluto
```

Issues in my CSV file:

1. My date is not in proper format DD-MM-YY (as per R), In my dataset somewhere it is 01 Jan 01, somewhere 01.01.01 (unlike 01-01-01 required by R).
2. Time in CSV is also not in proper format 00:00:00, In my Dataset its given as 00:00
3. At times my time is having values like (00:00 to 10:01) which I want to filter either to 00:00 or remove the entire row.
4. Issues with Porduct_no, Product_IM_no and Pro_name is that they sometimes have other values than the given data structure. In such case , it should remove the entire row.

I am having 20 such CSVs which consist of 10k rows each approx. for which I need to resolve this issue. How can I solve such issues in R?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `lubridate` to change the multiple format in the date columns. Check `?parse_date_time`.  It would be helpful to show few lines of example data with these four issues and the expected output based on that.

Comment: @akrun Yes I did tried using lubridate (timeDate and parsing given in cran) and  chron libraries but I couldn't achieve what I wanted

Comment: The first row for time is `00:40 to 1:30`.  How do you want it in the expected output

Comment: @akrun I have updated a similar data like my CSV..

Comment: Thanks for that.  Do you want to expand the first row based on the time 00:40 to 1:30?

Comment: @akrun it should be either the 00:40:00 or 01:30:00.

Comment: @akrun no need for expansion. As after that I am also removing the duplicate data based on  `Product_no  Product_IM_no  Pro_Name`.. So if u expand they all have same values..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could `subset` the dataset with the rows that have only a single word in the 'Pro_Name' column using `grep`, keep the first time in the 'Time' column for multiple time strings (e.g. in the first row) using `sub`,   `paste` the 'Date', 'Time' columns, and using the `guess_formats` and `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` we create a 'DateTime' column which is of 'POSIXct' class.

```
library(lubridate) 
#subset the dataset rows
#we use \\w+ to match the a single word from the beginning of string'^'
#to the end of the string '$'.  If there are multiple words with spaces
#this returns FALSE.  Coupling it with `subset` will subset the TRUE rows. 
df2 <- subset(df1, grepl('^\\w+$', Pro_Name))
#remove the substring after the first space including the space using sub
df2$Time <- sub('\\s+.*$', '', df2$Time)
#paste the columns
v1 <- do.call(paste, df2[2:3])
#create new columns
df2$DateTime <- parse_date_time(v1, guess_formats(v1, c('dBy hm', 'dmy hm')))
#if we don't want to keep the original 'Date' and 'Time'
#we can remove that as well using `setdiff` on the column names of 'df2'
#and the columns that we don't want in the output
df2[setdiff(names(df2), c('Date', 'Time'))]
#  ID Product_no Product_IM_no Pro_Name            DateTime
#1  1     2152.5       71213.4   Aspire 2001-10-02 00:40:00
#2  1     2152.5       71213.4   Aspire 2001-10-02 01:30:00
#4  1    21537.9        7157.8    pluto 2001-10-02 02:50:00
```

#### data

```
df1 <-structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Date = c("2-Oct-01",
"2-Oct-01", 
"2-Oct-01", "2.10.01"), Time = c("00:40  to 1:30", "01:30", "02:10", 
"02:50"), Product_no = c(2152.5, 2152.5, 21547.9, 21537.9),
 Product_IM_no = c(71213.4, 
 71213.4, 7122.3, 7157.8), Pro_Name = c("Aspire", "Aspire",
 "Pla and Aspire", 
"pluto")), .Names = c("ID", "Date", "Time", "Product_no", 
"Product_IM_no", 
"Pro_Name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Akrun, Can't I split the DateTime into Date & Time sepratly?

Comment: @Flames I think using `chron`, you can keep it separate.  But, I would keep it as a single column of 'POSIXct' class from which you extract all the components or remove it by `format`

Comment: I am getting a warning message after which it is creating the DateTime column but filling NA values with it....
`Warning message: All formats failed to parse. No formats found`

Comment: @Flames You have to fill in the `guess_format` with the different formats you have.  In the example you showed, there is only 2 formats i.e. `c('dBy hm', 'dmy hm')`.  It means  day followed by month year hour minute or month in numeric `dmy hm`

Comment: @Flames Yes, you have use `dby` and `hms` if there is `db` or `hm` it won't work

Comment: but my all CSV files do not follow this format... In some files date and time is given in proper format..
`Data$DateTime <- parse_date_time(variab, guess_formats(variab, c('dBy hm', 'dmy hm','myd hm','ymd hm','ydm hm','dym hm','mdy hm','ymd hm')))`
Am I still missing something?

Comment: @Flames If there is a particular format missing you may need to `paste` it and then use the `format`.  I don't think this will work on that.  One option would be to `grep` for the elements that don't follow the pattern.  It would be better to post as a separate question as I  didn't expect it here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mainulate them manually. For example for converting your time, you can use strsplit function to split based on having "to":

```
gg <- strsplit("00:00 to 10:01", "to")
gg[[1]][1] #00:00 as an output
```

Edit: the problem is reading the file?

```
ff <- read.csv("test2.csv", header = T)
ff <- as.data.frame(ff)
for (i in 1:ff <- length(ff$Time) {...}
```